# Sessions > Clicks -- Adwords

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

Hope you're doing well.

For the past 1 week, our adwords campaigns have been reporting more sessions than clicks. Yesterday had the biggest discrepancies of 19% difference. What could be the reason behind this?

P/S : All accounts are properly linked.

PLease advise. Your input is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As this questions was submitted more then 1 million times now, Google created a good documentation on this:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4588315?hl=en